# how to have fixed height and variable width for a text

Tags: css, html, text, width

There is a `DIV` and a text inside it. this `DIV` must has 450px height and its width is variable but it must be so wide such that horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear and the `DIV` completely wrap the text. how do I can implement this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about what you're looking after, but if you want the `div` to get wide up to the horizontal space (as the containing block *width*) you could use `max-width` property while the `div` is displayed as `inline-block`:

```css
div {
  height: 450px;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline; /* <-- inline-block hack for IE 6/7 */
  *zoom: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: zoom is not supported in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Drupalist the **star-hacks** are only for **IE 6/7** as I mentioned. Happily remove that If you don't care about IE7 and below :)